# macrium error message: cannot clone volume while Windows is running

Tags: macrium

I want to clone my 128GB SSD boot drive to a 512GB SSD.

I open Macrium Reflect inside Windows 7 x64. When I identify the source and target drives, and eventually get to the point where I tell Macrium to proceed with the cloning, Macrium says it cannot complete the operation while Windows is running.  It says to boot from the PE repair disk.

So I boot from the PE repair disk, which brings up a Macrium splash screen with menu options.  But reflect.exe cannot be run from the PE command line.  I get an error message that oledlg.dll is missing.

All of the online videos showing how to clone a drive show Macrium already running, so I don't know where it has been booted from.

I'd be grateful for some advice.

Comment: Have you tried other software?

Comment: [Try Conezilla](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/how-do-i-clone-a-hard-drive-with-clonezilla/)